# pandas.concat using only the index from one table

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm looking for a more efficient way to concatenate two dataframes that have a `DatetimeIndex`. Considering I want only the dates from the first, and all data from the second:

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

a = StringIO('''
Time,No,Value
2017-10-17 04:00:00,1,10
2017-10-17 04:01:00,2,10
2017-10-17 04:02:00,3,10
2017-10-17 04:03:00,4,10
2017-10-17 04:04:00,5,10
''')

b = StringIO('''
Time,Str
2017-10-17 04:00:00,a
2017-10-17 04:02:00,b
''')

df1 = pd.read_csv(a).set_index('Time')
df2 = pd.read_csv(b).set_index('Time')
```

What I currently do is include one useless column, and then delete it:

```
>>> df = pd.concat([df1.No, df2], axis=1)
>>> print(df)
                    No  Str
Time                        
2017-10-17 04:00:00   1    a
2017-10-17 04:01:00   2  NaN
2017-10-17 04:02:00   3    b
2017-10-17 04:03:00   4  NaN
2017-10-17 04:04:00   5  NaN

>>> del df['No']
>>> print(df)
                    Str
Time                    
2017-10-17 04:00:00    a
2017-10-17 04:01:00  NaN
2017-10-17 04:02:00    b
2017-10-17 04:03:00  NaN
2017-10-17 04:04:00  NaN
```

Expected command **(this doesn't work)**:

```
>>> pd.concat([df1.index, df2], axis=1)
                    Str
Time                    
2017-10-17 04:00:00    a
2017-10-17 04:01:00  NaN
2017-10-17 04:02:00    b
2017-10-17 04:03:00  NaN
2017-10-17 04:04:00  NaN
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what you want in a simpler form:

```
df2.reindex(df1.index)
```

Answer (score 1):

Either reindex, as suggested in the first answer, or this:

```
pd.concat([df1.No, df2], axis=1)['Str']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`df.join`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html), which joins two dataframes on `index` by default:

```
In [180]: df2.join(df1, how='outer')['Str']
Out[180]: 
Time
2017-10-17 04:00:00      a
2017-10-17 04:01:00    NaN
2017-10-17 04:02:00      b
2017-10-17 04:03:00    NaN
2017-10-17 04:04:00    NaN
Name: Str, dtype: object
```